# Is there a way to insert a count of elapsed minutes in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a todo.txt file, and I think it'd be fun to be able to position my cursor on a todo item (a line in my todo.txt file), press a key combination, and have Vim start counting the minutes. Then, when I press another key combination, it would stop counting, and insert the number of minutes elapsed, like `min:25`. Is there a way to do that in vim?

What would also be awesome is if I pressed the key combination on a line already beginning `min:`, it would append the minutes to those existing minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with it and came up with the following script.  To make it reliable I had to make it handle the format of "`minMM:SS`" where `MM` and `SS` are minutes and seconds.

I suspect you will need to modify this somehow to fit your actual needs, but the script basically starts counting when you type, in normal mode, the key sequence: `\sc`

Then it will stop counting and append to the cursor position the above mentioned format when you type the key sequence: `\ec`

If the line already contains a time stamp matching the above format, it will add to it instead.

Note that if you have changed your `mapleader` you would use that instead of `\` in the above key sequences.

```
function! s:Start()
    if exists('b:CountMinutesStart')
        echohl ERROR
        echomsg "Already counting."
        echohl NONE
        return
    endif

    echohl TODO
    echomsg "Counting started."
    echohl NONE
    let b:CountMinutesStart = localtime()
endfunction

function! s:Stop()
    if !exists('b:CountMinutesStart')
        echohl ERROR
        echomsg "Not counting."
        echohl NONE
        return -1
    endif

    let l:start = b:CountMinutesStart
    let l:end = localtime()
    unlet b:CountMinutesStart
    let l:elapsed = l:end - l:start

    echohl TODO
    echomsg "Elapsed time since start: " . s:Format(l:elapsed)
    echohl NONE

    return l:elapsed
endfunction

function! s:Format(seconds)
    let l:minutes = a:seconds / 60
    let l:seconds = a:seconds % 60
    return printf('min%02d:%02d', l:minutes, l:seconds)
endfunction

function! s:InsertTime()
    let l:seconds = s:Stop()
    if l:seconds == -1
        return
    endif
    let l:line = getline('.')
    if l:line =~ 'min\d\{2}:\d\{2}'
        let l:tmp = split(substitute(l:line, '.*min\(\d\{2}\):\(\d\{2}\).*', '\1 \2', ''), ' ')
        let l:seconds = l:seconds + (l:tmp[0] * 60 + l:tmp[1])
        call setline('.', substitute(l:line, 'min\d\{2}:\d\{2}', s:Format(l:seconds), ''))
    else
        exe 'normal a' . s:Format(l:seconds)
    endif
endfunction

command! StartCounting call s:Start()
command! StopCounting call s:InsertTime()

nmap <silent> <leader>sc :StartCounting<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>ec :StopCounting<cr>
```

Comment: Awesome. I had to change `'normal a'` to `'normal A' . ' '`, but otherwise it works like a charm! Thanks!